# Precise meaning of various terms related to universal hash functions

Tags: hash, terminology, universal-hash

I've been reading about universal hashing, but I'm confused by all these different terms and notations.  Could someone help me understand the precise meaning or relation between the following terms:

- universal hash family
- pairwise independent hash functions
- 2-universal hash family
- strongly universal hash family
- delta-universal hash family

Comment: We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: Really got confused by looking at the terms with different explanations and notations in different papers and books. unhappy with the treatment got by posting it here. probably this is my last question. let me do my homework.

Comment: With all due respect, your question shows no research effort whatsoever and looks like it's almost a verbatim copy from an assignment. On top of that there are multiple seperate questions there that should be a standalone question. On stackexchange we strive to be useful to future visitors by building up a knowledge base, and the question in your current form is unlikely to be as useful and clear for future visitors as it would be if you asked seperate questions. That's the reason why I downvoted and said we're not here to do your homework - there's no need to feel insulted.